# Cant get my added div removed

Tags: jquery

I added some elements to my page with the following code, which works fine:

```
$("body").on("click", "#buttonadd", function(){
    var vriend = "<div id='friends'><h4>Jaap Smit</h4><div class='unfollow'><a href='#' class='removefriend'>Delete friend</a></div></div>";
    $(this).parent().siblings(".currentfriends").append(vriend);
});
```

However when I try to remove this using the following code, nothing will happen...

```
$("body").on("click", "a.removefriend", function(){
    $(this).closest('.vriend').remove();
});
```

Been trying for quite some time now but I have no idea how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing with class `vriend`. You may want to remove `#friends`.

```
$("body").on("click", "a.removefriend", function(){
    $(this).closest('#friends').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove an object with the class "vriend" by using `$(".vriend")`, not the defined variable. Since (at least int the code shown) there is no fitting target nothing happends.
 Try `$(this).closest(vriend).remove();` instead.